# How to update the DOM using chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal function callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome app that received an address from an extension and is supposed to open that URL in the app window, using the webview tag and Chrome runtime API message sending.

I'm trying to get the chrome.window.create callback function to update the index.html page the was created. 
It's not working as I planned though.

Here is the code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(

function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

    chrome.app.window.create(

        'index.html',

        {PARAMETERS},

        function () {

            //get 
            var thisWindow = document.querySelector("webview");

            thisWindow.setAttribute("src", request.url);

        }
    );
}
```

The index.html file is just a webview tag and some styling.

This opens an empty window once the message is received. However, it opens the page when I send again while the app is open, meaning that the callback probably tried to access the index.html file before it was created?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: where is the `document` variable being set?

Comment: @levi Thanks for replying. The index.html is in the same directory as the script. As I understand, the first parameter refers to this index file, which contains the webview tag. Also, it does show the page when there is an app window already open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.create` callback function is called prior to the execution of the created windows `onload` event ([see here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create)). So presumably the DOM is not yet available at this stage. What you can do is, bind your modifications to the created windows `onload` event, thus ensuring the DOM is available.

```
chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html', 
    {
        PARAMETERS
    },
    function (createdWindow) {
        var contentWindow = createdWindow.contentWindow;
        contentWindow.onload = function() {
            var thisWindow = contentWindow.document.querySelector("webview");
            thisWindow.setAttribute("src", request.url);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like it's working. I've tried that approach before but without referring to the createdWindow parameter.